# How to fetch the result of a query in Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, average

I need to get the avg score in a variable. I am using zend and I have tried two queries and none of them are working:

```
$avg_query = $db->query("SELECT sid, AVG(score) 
                         FROM markstable GROUP BY sid");

$avg_query = $db->query("SELECT sid, AVG(score) 
                         FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");

$avg_score = $db->fetchAll($avg_query);
echo $avg_score; gives nothing
echo $avg_score['$sid']; gives nothing
```

I need to store the `avg_score` in some other table.

Comment: Which Zend are you using? Zf1 or Zf2?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to fetch avg grouped by sid.

```
$avg_score = $db->fetchAll("SELECT sid,AVG(score) FROM st GROUP BY sid");

foreach($avg_score as $row) {
    echo $row["sid"]."  ".$row["AVG(score)"];
}
```

In case of second query :

```
$avg_score = $db->fetchRow("SELECT sid,AVG(score) FROM st where sid=1");
echo $avg_score["AVG(score)"];
```

Comment: There should be an equal sign in the second example. Since I haven't reached 2k points yet I cannot edit posts which require edits of <6 characters. Which is kinda ridiculous.

Comment: Better late than never I guess :')

Answer (score 0):

Try fetchPairs() instead of fetchAll()

Edit: Zend_Db does have a fetchPairs();

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchpairs

Also remove quotes from round the variable in the array index

```
echo $avg_score[$sid];
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed syntax in your attempt to query the DB.

The [`query()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.creating) method builds and executes the desired query. Your first query should return the result, no need to provide any further code:

```
$avg_query = $db->query("SELECT sid, AVG(score) FROM markstable GROUP BY sid");
Zend_debug::dump($avg_query);//same as var_dump but already includes <pre> tags
```

your second query needs to include any bound values in an array as the second argument:

```
$avg_query = $db->query("SELECT sid, AVG(score) FROM markstable WHERE sid = ?", array($sid);
Zend_debug::dump($avg_query);//same as var_dump but already includes <pre> tags
```

you can also execute this query using a standard fetch method, just pass in the SQL as a string:

```
$avg_score = $db->fetchAll("SELECT sid, AVG(score) FROM markstable GROUP BY sid");
Zend_debug::dump($avg_score);//same as var_dump but already includes <pre> tags
```

when dealing with `Zend_Db` components you may as well get used to using placeholders in your queries (`?`) as the old style syntax has been deprecated in many of the components.

This is probably not the best solution to what you're doing. It does however answer your question. There are a rather large number of ways to interact with a database in Zend Framework and using `Zend_Db_Adapter` components and methods are typically not the best way to accomplish the task.